# Show that the solution of f'(x)=-af(x)+ag(x) depends continuous on its initial value

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the solution of f'(x)=-af(x)+ag(x) depends continuous on its initial value.
So given the differential equation $f'(x)=-af(x)+ag(x)$ with $f(0)=p$ , $x \geq 0$
, find a Constant C such that:
$||f||_{C^1} \leq C ||g||_{C^0}$

Note that
$||f||_{C^1}=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$

and

$||g||_{C^0}=||g||_\infty$

My Approach:
First I solved the equation above,
$f(x)=e^{-ax}(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)$

Using $||f||_{C^1}=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$
und inserting the solution I get

$||f||_{C^1}=sup_{x \in [0,t]}|e^{-ax}(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)|$+$sup_{x \in [0,t]}|-ae^{-ax}(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds+e^{-ax}+ae^{ax}g(x)|$

I split this into two parts:

First:

$sup_{x \in [0,t]}|e^{-ax}(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)|=sup_{x \in [0,t]}|(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)| \leq sup_{x \in [0,t]}(|p|+ |a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds|)$

thats how far I got in the first part, I don't really know how to estimate the part with the Integral, especially because I don't know g.

Second:

$sup_{x \in [0,t]}|-ae^{-ax}(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)+e^{-ax}+ae^{ax}g(x)|=sup_{x \in [0,t]}|-a(p+a\int_0^x e^{as}g(s)ds)+1+g(x)|$

$||g||_{C^0}=sup_{x \in [0,t]}|g(x)|$

I don't know how to find this C. Hope someone could show me how.